# Почему не срабатывает запись в куку для всего поддомена?

Tags: javascript

Требуется сохранить куку для всех под доменов, но не получается.

Что не так? Код:

```
function cetcooke(status) {
                var date = new Date;
                var SERVER_NAME = ".site.ru";
                date.setDate(date.getDate() + 15); // время жизни куки
                document.cookie = "sound="+ status +"; expires="+date.toUTCString()+"; path='"+SERVER_NAME+"'"; // ставим куку 
}
```

нажимаю на кнопочку сохраняет как для определенной страницы, но не для домена.

Помогите решить проблему.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Не верно в path данные записываете. Нужно так:

```
path="/"
```

А то что у Вас в переменной `var SERVER_NAME = ".site.ru";` нужно записывать в `domain`

Вот у меня всегда есть функция для создание cookie:

```
function set_cookie ( name, value, exp_y, exp_m, exp_d, path, domain, secure )
{
  var cookie_string = name + "=" + escape ( value );

  if ( exp_y )
  {
    var expires = new Date ( exp_y, exp_m, exp_d );
    cookie_string += "; expires=" + expires.toGMTString();
  }

  if ( path )
        cookie_string += "; path=" + escape ( path );

  if (domain)
        cookie_string += "; domain=" + escape (domain);

  if ( secure )
        cookie_string += "; secure";

  document.cookie = cookie_string;
}
```

Вот так использую:

```
set_cookie('nameCookie', "valueInCookie", 0, 0, 0, "/");
```

Comment: помогло, спасибо.